# Name for build option (for "make install") specifying where to install web application

Tags: web-applications, installation, makefile

I want to provide 'install' target for Makefile for web application.  I'd like to be able to install it, for example like described below:

```
$ make install \
    xxxdir=/var/www/cgi-bin
```

(similarly to how one would use 'bindir' for ordinary programs, and 'mandir' / 'infodir' for documentation).

Is there any standard (similar to autotools 'bindir', 'sharedir', etc.) for the ***name*** of **'xxxdir'** variable in above example?

How do you think should such build configuration variable be named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web application lingo usually refers to deployments, rather than installs, so that would suggest `deploydir`.